# Show that $(-1)^a5^b \equiv (-1)^{a'}5^{b'} \mod 2^l$, $ l\geq 3$ implies $(-1)^a \equiv (-1)^{a'} \mod 4$ and $a\equiv a' \mod 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading Ireland's *A classical introduction to modern number theory*. I find it hard to understand a part of a proof in the book. Can anyone explain it for me?

> If $(-1)^a5^b \equiv (-1)^{a'}5^{b'}\mod 2^l$, $ l\geq 3$,$\,$ then $(-1)^a \equiv (-1)^{a'} \mod 4$, implying that $a\equiv a' \mod 2$.

Comment: By the first dupe and $4\mid 2^l,\,$ the congruence persists $\!\bmod 4\,$ yielding $\, (-1)^a\equiv (-1)^{a'}\pmod{\!4},\,$ so $\,a\equiv a'\pmod{\!\color{#c00}2}\,$  by $\,{\rm ord}_{\:\!4}(-1)=\color{#c00}2\,$ and *mod order reduction* (2nd dupe). $\ \ $